# What are these bowls of blue water in Star Trek TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Why are there bowls of blue water on the night stands in Star Trek: The Next Generation?

In multiple episodes, there is a small bowl with blue liquid next to the bed on a table.

For example, from TNG 5x18, [Cause and Effect](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)):
[image: Crusher's bedstand]

Comment: Ha ha!   @dana probably doesn't know how to use the three shells either!   http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--jpqoux6U--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_320/jkw4tdpn1kvljw67zdb4.jpg

Comment: @Omegacron TNG 5x18, _Cause and Effect_, next to Dr. Crusher's bed, next to the glass she keeps breaking

Comment: One that's likely regular water turned blue by the curve of the bowl. Two, I doubt there's a specific answer outside of ***it was a neat decor item***.

Comment: Coming back, the only think I can think of given its odd shape is some sort of futuristic humidifier.  But the ship's environmental controls should handle that.

Comment: @Izkata - Or filled with scent to make the room smell nice

Comment: With all of the bathroom appliances being energy-based, the blue water was probably for use when all of the power was diverted to shields and life support.

Comment: Based on the shape, it's to prevent water from spilling out at the slightest turbulence. It could be scented oil, or in my opinion, it's there so they can wipe the sleep out of their face/eyes when they wake up, dipping their fingers in and splash it on their face.

Comment: It's obviously Romulan Ale.

Comment: Just to confirm: Has a bowl like this been seen in rooms other than Dr. Crusher's?

Comment: FWIW, in sickbay there's a table with alternating containers of blue and red liquid. Most likely set decoration with no practical purpose.

Comment: @RyanVeeder Yes, one is visible in Riker's room in 6x05 about 10 minutes in, he puts his glass of milk down next to it

Comment: Maybe rather than scent it emits some sort of sleep enhancing vapour

Answer (score 8):

## 24th Century Feng Shui

I've tried hard to research this question since it was posted, with two obstacles:

- next to nothing has been published about tabletop decorations on *TNG* (as opposed to wall art, for which there is a lot more information, e.g. [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108294/what-is-this-painting-on-the-enterprise-showing) and [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108294/what-is-this-painting-on-the-enterprise-showing))
- the principal set decorator for *TNG*, [Jim Mees](http://www.startrek.com/article/remembering-trek-set-decorator-james-mees-1955-2013), died three years ago (and doesn't seem to have remarked upon the bowl of blue liquid before that)

However, the bowl immediately struck me as being *Feng Shui* in nature.

[image]

There do appear to be Feng Shui connections to *TNG*-era Star Trek: for instance, the 2007 television series [*Feng Shui Living*](http://www.rodpylefilms.com/feng_shui_living_56823.htm) was created and produced by Rod Pyle, who was previously a visual consultant for *DS9* who worked closely with Mees and with Star Trek designers Rick Sternbach and Michael Okuda.  (Sternbach contributed much of the wall art for the *TNG* sets.)

**Based on the above, my best guess is that, both in-universe and out-of-universe, the bowl of blue liquid is just some 24th Century Feng Shui.**

(Either that, or Beverly needs a *lot* of Romulan ale to get to sleep at night...)

Comment: I assumed it was scented water to make the bedroom smell nice

Answer (score 7):

My good friend [Alan Sims](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alan_Sims) (Property Master for Star Trek: TNG) was kind enough to address this. In short, they were most likely just used as futuristic-looking set-dressing with **no actual in-universe purpose other than as background decoration.**

> **Q.** ***Purely out of interest, what was the weird bowl of blue liquid in the same scene used for? I always figured it was some kind of room scent.***
>
> **AS:** *...It sounds like it was a piece of set dressing via ‘Set Decorator’ and they would have just used blue food coloring with H<sub>2</sub>O*

Comment: Was this an email exchange, twitter, something else? And what is the "same scene" you refer to?

Comment: @Martha - Via email and in reference to [this scene with Dr Crusher's broken glass](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192491/what-is-the-manufacturer-brand-of-the-glass-that-dr-crusher-breaks)