# Where is this painting from the Enterprise now?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, props, art

This is a follow on to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108294/what-is-this-painting-on-the-enterprise-showing) and of course [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108295/3823) regarding this painting:

[image]

[image]
[image]

which we now know is a depiction by [Rick Sternbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Sternbach) of the glideship Aurora and its hydrogen balloon, used to drop into the atmosphere of Jupiter in *The Anvil of Jove* by Gregory Benford and Gordon Eklund.

## Where is this painting now?

Comment: I've got a +200 bounty for a solid answer on this.   I won't post it yet so it doesn't expire before someone can find the answer.

Comment: Very little of the artwork seems to have gone to auction. Most likely it's in Sternbach's personal collection or among the stuff that Paramount held onto for the Best of Trek exhibitions.

Comment: You want to attract answers, start your bounty. Promising a possible bounty in the comments doesn't really do much for attracting actual attention and isn't really how bounties are supposed to work.

Comment: In-universe or out of it? The original or the prop (if there's a difference)?

Comment: @TARS Agreed, but often the bounty-period is just to awfully short. I would be perfectly happy to put a bounty on a question to award it months later when an answer shows up.

Comment: @TARS:   Yes, it's only because the bounty disappears if not awarded within a week.   I am giving my word.   I'll start of +50 bounty now, just to attract attention, but I'm promising more.    (Oh, I can't do any bounty for a few days, so you'll just have to take my word.)

Comment: @SQB:  Regarding *the original or the prop*:   We can say with very high confidence that the one shown on the show is the original.   There's no indication from any of the research in the linked answer that a copy was ever produced or why one would do so.

Comment: @SQB: Out-of-universe. In-universe, we can probably presume it was destroyed along with the Enterprise-D unless there was extensive scavenging of parts, but that doesn't seem like it would be worth the effort for a painting when you have access to replicators.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Just so you know, I *am* working on this.  ;-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## The painting is a reproduction.  The original was sold at a convention before *TNG* aired.

I found this out by asking Rick Sternbach directly, via his professional [web site](http://ricksternbach.com/).

In my email to him:

> I'm writing to you because I am a member of "Scifi StackExchange", a question and answer forum on sci-fi works.   On the site, there have been a couple of recent questions regarding a painting that appears on one of the set walls of the Enterprise-D (Shelby's guest quarters in "Best of Both Worlds").  This painting is the cover that you made for "The Anvil of Jove".
>
> We're wondering: was the painting in the guest quarters the original painting?  Also, what was the fate of that particular painting?  Was it auctioned off?
>
> Thanks for your time.  Also, I hope it's okay if I post the answer to the forum.

His response:

> Heh. We never used originals on set, of course (with the exception of the Enterprise in Picard’s ready room, and that painting was locked away after filming), but large prints made from color transparencies and negs. The original for Anvil of Jove was sold at some SF convention ages before TNG. I just gave our set decorator a pile of images and he picked ones he liked for the sets.
>
> Thanks for the interest, though. Were a lot of fun years working on those shows.
>
> All the best,
>
> Rick

**Summary:**

- Original painting: sold off at some sci-fi convention (exact whereabouts unknown)
- Reproduction seen in *TNG*: whereabouts unknown

Since not a lot of artwork used in the Enterprise quarters have gone to auction (as per my research on the [Star Trek Prop Authority](http://www.startrekpropauthority.com/) and other similar groups), I assume that it is either in the hands of the set decorator who made the reproduction, or was kept by some other *TNG* personnel, or is under lock and key for future auctions or Star Trek conventions, or was pulped.  The last option is the least likely, but still possible.  The second-to-last option is not likely either, considering that Rick made a point of mentioning that the Ready Room painting is the kind of decoration worthy of being locked away.

So my best guess is that the reproduction seen in the guest quarters is in the hands of some (unknown) member of the *TNG* design crew.

Comment: wow.   Just wow.   I don't think I can accept because we don't actually know the answer,  but this deserves 50 upvotes.   Did you link him to these two questions? I'd love to see his comments.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I've added a few more comments to the end.  :-)

Comment: sure,  +50 when the system will let me.  But there's still a much bigger bounty for whoever can identify the current location of the original and/or reproduction.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Cool.  I'll obviously keep thinking about it.  :-)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I should add, he responded to me within an hour!  :-)