# Did Milano or Benatar approve or comment on their namesake MCU ships?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spaceship, guardians-of-the-galaxy

Peter Quill has named two [M-ships](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/M-ships) after his childhood crushes:  the [Milano](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Milano) and the [Benatar](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Benatar), named after  1980s actor [Alyssa Milano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alyssa_Milano) and singer [Pat Benatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat_Benatar).

**Were Milano and/or Benatar consulted?   Compensated?   Have they commented?**

Comment: On a related note: [Sundance: Kevin Bacon Reacts to 'Guardians of the Galaxy's' Kevin Bacon Jokes](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/kevin-bacon-reacts-guardians-galaxys-766807)

Comment: I can't find anything out about Pat Benatar liking/disliking the name. I've reached out to her through the usual channels. Hopefully she'll respond in due course.

Comment: You do not, in general, consult or compensate anyone for pop-culture references in fiction.

Comment: @Valorum - I don't think these questions are intended to be a venue for original reporting, but I'm wishing you luck anyway. :-)

Comment: @OrangeDog:   Certainly naming a ship after someone could cross the line into profiting from their fame.   Anyways, the fact you don't need to doesn't mean they didn't ask as a courtesy.

Comment: @ThePopMachine no, not at all.

Comment: What would Quill have known Milano from? I've never heard of her before, and it doesn't look like she had an extensive filmography before his '88 abduction.

Comment: @AzorAhai,  *Who's the Boss?* was a major sitcom that aired on network TV from 1984 to 1992.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Did 10 year olds watch it? Lol

Comment: @AzorAhai:   Most definitely.   I don't seem to be able to track it down, but it would have aired daytime or primetime.

Comment: @AzorAhai I'm very close to Quill in age, and I *absolutely* watched *Who's the Boss* in that timeframe.

Comment: @MichaelW.:   The real question is whether you had a crush on Alyssa Milano?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Nope! I hadn't discovered girls yet in 1988. If I was abducted in 1988 and had to name my favorite person from pop culture, it probably would have been Michael J Fox...

Comment: @T.E.D. - It's not at all uncommon for celebs and behind-the-scenes to respond to questions. We're not just about googling...

Comment: @T.E.D. - For example; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/213624/20774 or https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/137320/20774

Comment: @T.E.D.:   One of my favorites https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/119470/3823 mostly because it's related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108294/what-is-this-painting-on-the-enterprise-showing

Comment: @AzorAhai 10-year-olds definitely watched it. Most of the popular sitcoms from the '80s were sitcoms designed for families to watch together. Shows like _Who's the Boss_, _Family Ties_, _Growing Pains_, _The Cosby Show_, and _Roseanne_ were carefully tailored to appeal to both kids and adults.

Comment: And, I'm a year older than Chris Pratt (so presumably pretty close to the age that Quill is supposed to be), and Alyssa Milano was my first celebrity crush. Although I couldn't say for sure if that crash had developed by 1988 or not.

Comment: Hopefully, Peter Quill took advantage of his time on Earth to have a look at Alyssa Milano in Charmed...

Answer (score 56):

> **Q. How do you feel to have a ship named after you in Guardians of the Galaxy?**
>
> **Alyssa Milano:** *Pretty much the coolest thing EVER!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Reddit: Ask Me Anything](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/6rlavk/i_am_alyssa_milano_ask_me_anything/dl5yck4/)</sup></sub>