# Early 2000s science fiction book with a cyborg girl and Jupiter dirigibles

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for the title of a sci-fi book with a character who is a girl that was manipulated genetically or technologically to be able to communicate with an alien species from Jupiter. Her intestines were replaced by the communications device, which was later removed by a doctor who thought it was a kind of parasite. Somewhere along the book, she is addicted to a drug and lives in the ventilation shaft of a spaceship, or maybe just a ship. The contact with the aliens ends up being made by a cyborg man in a dirigible.

During her infancy/teen years the girl used to like a lake designed as a  mandelbrot fractal.

Comment: The mandelbrot fractal lake is in a late book by Arthur Clarke. I'm unable to check at this time but it might be one of the dire 2001 sequels or the one about an asteroid on collision course with Earth.

Comment: Venus Prime series by Paul Preuss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got it, with many thanks to Organic Marble and Ayshe. It was indeed the Venus Prime Series by Arhtur C. Clarke and Paul Preuss. Thanks for the suggestions and help

Comment: Can you explain why it matches for later querents? :)

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't match everything you mentioned, any chance you a confusing it with [The Anvil of Jove](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108295/3823) by Gregory Benford and Gordon Eklund which you might have read about on this site in the linked answer?

It has:

- a genetically manipulated girl
- alien species on Jupiter
- a brain-in-a-box genetically manipulated individual (i.e. cyborg)
- the brain-in-a-box makes contact after descending into the Jovian atmosphere in a dirigible-like vehicle.

[image]

Comment: read a bit of the anvil of jove, and it does not match, but thanks.

Comment: re-reading now, from the start of the series, when i find the match for the relevant parts will post