# What is the manufacturer/brand of the glass that Dr. Crusher breaks?

Tags: star-trek, object-identification, props

In “Cause and Effect”, Dr. Crusher breaks this glass. Anybody have a clue who the manufacturer/brand this glass is from and/or the model?

[image]

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Comparing against the grainy blown-up image that I can [now actually see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313779/275243), I don't see any obvious differences compared to Valorum's link.  Maybe the cup is a bit shallower?  But it's hard to tell with her thumb covering it.

Comment: It’s a cordial glass. They hold significantly less than a champagne flute (1-2 oz rather than 6 or so).

Comment: Compare also [any of these glasses](https://www.google.com/search?q=champagne+flute+trumpet+shaped&tbm=isch).

Comment: @Valorum, the one you linked has quite an obvious inverted hemisphere where the stem meets the base which I don't see in the prop.

Comment: I had already looked at the “obvious” Google results but couldn’t find one that fits this one. (If you have Netflix or Hulu you can pull up the scene by selecting Star Trek: The Next Generation, S05E18, time Index 0:15:15 (ca.) for a better view but Netflix doesn’t let me take a screenshot unfortunately). I would agree however that it’s a cordial glass, not a champagne glass. It only holds a sip or two. Sorry again for the bad image quality.

Comment: @Rere play it in a web browser and screenshot the browser.

Comment: I tried looking into old Star Trek auctions and couldn't find anything

Comment: here's a better image: http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/observations/causeandeffect/10-causeandeffect-r.jpg

Comment: Thanks, that’s a good picture.

Comment: I honestly don't see the point of this question.   There doesn't seem to be anything particularly interesting about this glass or its story.    Who made that bowl with the blue liquid in it?   What type and brand of coloring did they use to make it blue?

Comment: Of course, I don't have a problem with [object-identification] questions in general.  (See [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108294/what-is-this-painting-on-the-enterprise-showing)), but there should at least be something noteworthy about it.

Comment: As indicated already, it's a cordial glass. If you google image, there are several different styles, some of which are very similar to the above.

Comment: @JohnP - A search for those gets you very close; https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1396&bih=667&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=-ylrW5aIFqvNgAbQja7oBw&q=trumpet+cordial+glass+plain+stem&oq=trumpet+cordial+glass+plain+stem&gs_l=img.3...47949.49826.0.50055.11.11.0.0.0.0.144.965.6j4.10.0....0...1c.1.64.img..1.1.129...35i39k1.0.TQqHAEvlokc - This one (https://scottishantiques.com/image/cache/catalog/---/2017/201703/2017030175/IMG_5004-500x500.JPG) for example is almost identical

Comment: @ThePopMachine - consider cosplayers, set design or episode detail researchers or any number of other reasons why any given item in a well known franchise might be of interest to somebody

Comment: @Rere - Not only can you buy the glass, but because it's made of brittle plastic, you can encourage your wife to smash it over your head without causing any injury.

Answer (score 21):

My good friend [Alan Sims](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alan_Sims) (Props Master for TNG) advises me via email that while he can't recall the *specific* glass used, given that it was used in a scene where it broke, it was almost certainly provided by their long-term supplier [Alfonso's Breakaway Glass Inc](http://alfonsosbreakawayglass.com/).

There's an extremely similar glass (marked as a "*liqueur glass*") in their [current catalogue](http://alfonsosbreakawayglass.com/products/Glass/Glasses/Liqueur/132/).

[image]

Comment: Didn’t actually know what a breakaway glass is. Called them. Now I know. Won’t serve my purpose unfortunately unless I rly only wanna look at it on the shelf

Comment: That's the type of glass that schnapps is usually drunk from in Denmark.

Comment: Looks like it except the Danish schnapps glasses look generally shorter